# Geodesics on arbitrary 2D surfaces

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, geodesy, variational-calculus

**Geodesics on 2D Function Surfaces**

I am trying to approximately find the shortets path between two point on a surface defined as z=F[x,y]. I am solving for X,Y as function t. However, when trying to solve for the path, I get a **Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives** and **Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value 

problems** error. My code can be seen below:

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
F[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
Subscript[F, 1] = F[x[t], y[t]];
l = EulerEquations[Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 + (D[Subscript[F, 1], t])^2], {x[t], y[t]}, t];
s = NDSolveValue[{Simplify[Part[l, 1]], Simplify[Part[l, 2]], x[0] == 2, y[0] == 1, x[1] == 5, y[1] == 2}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 2}]

NDSolveValue::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations
NDSolveValue::bvdae: Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value problems
```

I dont understand why I am getting these errors. If you can help, let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` might help.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for the answer, this only solves the " Cannot Find an explicit formula for derivative error". I am still however getting the "Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value problems" Error. Is there a Way to get rid of this error? Thanks

Comment: If you write `l` as a matrix equation by means of CoefficientArrays[l // Simplify, {x''[t], y''[t]}]`, you will find that `% // Last // Det` equals `0`.  In other words, `NDSolve` cannot solve for both `{x''[t], y''[t]}` .  Ar you sure that you have formulated your problem correctly?  [This](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/minimizing-arc-length.101533/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

The problem above calls for determining the geodesic curve between points `{2,1}` and `{5,2}` on a paraboloid.  This can be done as follows.

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
z[x] = x^2 + y[x]^2
```

The resulting Euler equation is

```
eq = EulerEquations[Sqrt[1 + y'[x]^2 + D[z[x], x]^2], y[x], x]
(* (4 x y'[x] + 4 x y'[x]^3 - 4 y[x] (1 + y'[x]^2) - (1 + 4 x^2) y''[x] - 4 y[x]^2 y''[x])/
   (1 + y'[x]^2 + 4 (x + y[x] y'[x])^2)^(3/2) == 0 *)
```

which is easily solved by

```
soly = NDSolveValue[{eq, y[2] == 1, y[5] == 2}, y[x], x];
```

and plotted on the paraboloid.

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{x, soly, x^2 + soly^2}, {x, 2, 5}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 50}} , AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
    Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Mesh -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: If we pick two opposing points, e.g. $p_1=\{-5,0\}$ and $p_2=\{5,0\}$ this yields a geodesic that is made up of two parabolic arcs that meet at the origin. Is this really the shortest path connecting $p_1$ and $p_2$?